# Angular push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, push

I have two tables: `site` and `ip`.

`site`: site_id,name

`ip`: ip_id,site_id,ip_adress

I have to show a list of `ip_adress` of a site.

**html**

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">
        <button style="margin-bottom:5px;" ng-click="addIp($index)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none">
            <li ng-repeat="ip in site.ips  track by $index">
            <div class="input-group" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ip_adress" style="display: inline;" ng-model="ip.ip_adress" required />
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" ng-click="removeIp(site, ip, $index)"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.addIp = function(index){  
  $scope.sites[index].ips[index].ip_adress.push(""); 
}
```

It throws this error:

> `$scope.sites[index].ips[index].ip_adress.push is not a function`

Ips is a Set of Ip object, and ip_adress is a String.
How can i resolve this ?

Comment: should it be `ip_address`

Comment: *"ip_adress is a String"* – Yes, and strings don't have a method `.push`. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: you saiid , ip_adress is a string, push is not a function of string, it should be used with an array.

Comment: Seems strange that index is same for inner and outer arrays also.

Comment: you should first initialize an array on ip_address like so: $scope.sites[index].ips[index].ip_adress=[]; as mentionned above, push() is an array method

Comment: Provide [mcve] that includes data structure sample

Comment: With addIp($index) the $index is not in scope of the ng-repeat so it does not know what that is.

Comment: `$index` does not appear to be defined where you call this in view

Comment: in the view your are using $index ng-click="addIp($index)", well before ng-repeat as well, that is also an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, i resolve it:

Comment: Thanks for your helps, i resolve it.

`$scope.sites[index].ips.push({
      ip_id  : "",
      site_id : $scope.sites[index].site_id,
      ip_adress : "",
    });`

But now when i save or make a modification by calling `site.$update()` , the site parameter of the ip object is null. How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should push to your array like: `$scope.sites[index].ips.push(<here_goes_your_object_with_ip_string>);`

if `ips` is an array

Comment: Thanks for your helps, i resolve it.

`$scope.sites[index].ips.push({
      ip_id  : "",
      site_id : $scope.sites[index].site_id,
      ip_adress : "",
    });`

But now when i save or make a modification by calling `site.$update()` , the site parameter of the ip object is null. How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
$scope.addIp = function(index){  
  $scope.sites[index][ips[index]]['ip_adress'].push(""); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps, i resolve it.

`$scope.sites[index].ips.push({
      ip_id  : "",
      site_id : $scope.sites[index].site_id,
      ip_adress : "",
    });`

But now when i save or make a modification by calling `site.$update()` , the site parameter of the ip object is null. How can i resolve this ?